# How to write unit tests for proxy pattern?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns

Will be thankful for your attention, time and efforts ! 
I have the following code

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    Employee GetEmployee(string firstName, string role);
}

public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    public Employee GetEmployee(string firstName, string role)
    {
        //logic here
        return new Employee();
    }
}
```

Now i want to implement cache for `EmployeeRepository`.
At first i did it using Proxy design pattern

```
 public class ProxyEmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private EmployeeRepository _employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
    private MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache("UsualCache");
    public Employee GetEmployee(string firstName, string role)
    {
        //do not cache administrators
        if (role == "admin")
        {
            return _employeeRepository.GetEmployee(firstName, role);
        }
        else
        {
            //get from cache  at first
            //if absent call _employeeRepository.GetEmployee and add to cache
            //...
        }
    }
```

But when wanted to write unit tests for this class i couldn't do it(i cannot create mock for _employeeRepository  and verify whether it was called or not) 
If i implement cache with Decorator pattern then i would have the following  code

```
 public class DecoratorEmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
    public DecoratorEmployeeRepository(IEmployeeRepository repository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = repository;
    }

    private MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache("UsualCache");
    public Employee GetEmployee(string firstName, string role)
    {
        //do not cache administrators
        if (role == "admin")
        {
            return _employeeRepository.GetEmployee(firstName, role);
        }
        else
        {
            //get from cache  at first
            //if absent call _employeeRepository.GetEmployee and add to cache
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and unit tests for it

```
 [TestClass]
public class EmployeeRepositoryTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetEmployeeTest_AdminRole()
    {
        var innerMock = Substitute.For<IEmployeeRepository>();
        var employeeRepository = new DecoratorEmployeeRepository(innerMock);
        employeeRepository.GetEmployee("Ihor", "admin");
        innerMock.Received().GetEmployee(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<string>());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetEmployeeTest_NotAdminRole()
    {
        var innerMock = Substitute.For<IEmployeeRepository>();
        var employeeRepository = new DecoratorEmployeeRepository(innerMock);
        employeeRepository.GetEmployee("Ihor", "NotAdmin");
        innerMock.DidNotReceive().GetEmployee("Ihor", "NotAdmin");
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to write unit tests for first approach with proxy pattern ? i just don't understand how it is possible to cover proxy class with unit tests ...**

Comment: "But when wanted to write unit tests for this class i couldn't do it". What is the reason you "couldn't do it"?

Comment: You can test `ProxyEmployeeRepository`, but you can't test it in isolation without the `EmployeeRepository`. To be able to do this, you need to use the decorator pattern.

Comment: @Disappointed Let go back to the root that causes of the issue. You do not need to ProxyEmployeeRepository in order to use Cache *(unless you have a reason behind it)*; instead, we normally place caching logic inside GetEmployee method.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer your question but it might help other new visitors:

I think your problem is your misunderstanding of both patterns. By using composition instead of instantiating your class inside the proxy, does not necessarily mean that you have changed your pattern from proxy to decorator. Each of these patterns is solving a specific problem. Let me clarify each:

**Decorator Pattern:**
This pattern is useful when you have different kinds of behaviours in your main class (like caching, logging, lazy loading and etc.) and you want to use each of these or a combination of them in different places of your application. For example, in your controller, you need only caching, in the admin controller you don't need caching but logging and in another service, you need both plus lazy loading. Therefore you will create three decorators for each extra behaviour (caching, logging and lazy loading) and in each place, you link the decorators into each other to provide various kinds of behaviours. The benefit of this pattern is that each class has only one responsibility. Additionally, your application is open to extension and close to modification. If you need a new behaviour, you can simply implement a new decorator from the interface and add it only to the services or controllers that the new behaviour is required without modifying the current implementation.

**Proxy Pattern:**
This pattern is useful when you want to add specific behaviour or behaviours that are required for your class but can prevent the actual behaviour (querying the database) and/or new behaviours come into the picture (which is not the behaviour in the decorator pattern. It only enhances the main behaviour). Another usage of this pattern is when instantiating the main class is costly. So in contrast, you do not need each behaviour (or various combination of them) separately in several places of your application.
The benefit of this pattern is that it prevents adding several responsibilities to your main class. Besides, it is still close to modification and open to extension. If the requirements change in future, you can simply implement a new proxy and replace it with the correct one or use it separately.

**The answer to your question:**
Therefore, as I mentioned above, by having a composition to your interface instead of instantiating it directly, you are not changing the pattern. In proxy pattern, the main class can be injected via the interface or the concrete implementation as well.